# Simple solutions for an edited volume with Latex in scr-class

Tags: book-design

I googled a lot to find an easy way of typesetting an edited volume ("Sammelband") with Latex. There are some presets by publishing houses available on the web, yet they tend to come with complete styles and lots of baggage.

Since this place is the most complete compendium on all things Latex, it would be great to have a starting point here for people seeking simple ways to build an edited volume in latex with the least amount of hassle.

The combine class seems apt for conference proceedings but it feels a bit overkill (and overcomplicated w/ repeating packages etc.) for an issue where, essentially, the goal is a book with the only issue of each chapter having a separate author. (It seems to me this is a format most current in the humanities.)

Below is the best way I figured out to do this, but I would (naturally) be interested if others found different ways of achieving the same end more efficiently.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{filecontents*}{art1.tex} 
    \chapter{Article 1}
    \Blindtext[5]
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{art2.tex} 
    \chapter{Article 2}
    \Blindtext[7]
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents

    \cleardoublepage
    \input{art1.tex}

    \cleardoublepage
    \input{art2.tex}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution with koma-script is:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{blindtext}

% define some variables for later
\newcommand{\auth}{}
\newcommand{\contr}{}

% For the titles in the page header
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\cehead[]{\auth}
\cohead[]{\contr}

% No contribution sections in book toc 
\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}

\begin{filecontents*}{art1.tex} 
     % "fill" variables
    \renewcommand*{\auth}{John}
    \renewcommand*{\contr}{I love Hans}

    % add info to table of contents 
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\auth\newline\contr}

    % author before heading
    \setchapterpreamble[oc]{\begin{center}\auth\end{center}}

    % heading, with "*" since toc entry is done manually 
    \chapter*{\contr}

    \Blindtext[5]

\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{art2.tex} 
    % "fill" variables
    \renewcommand*{\auth}{Hans}
    \renewcommand*{\contr}{I love John}

    % add info to table of contents 
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\auth\newline\contr}

    % author before heading
    \setchapterpreamble[oc]{\begin{center}\auth\end{center}}

    % heading, with "*" since toc entry is done manually 
    \chapter*{\contr}

    \Blindtext[7]

\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \cleardoublepage
    \input{art1.tex}
    \cleardoublepage
    \input{art2.tex}

\end{document}
```

Basically, all it takes is copy-pasting the corresponding lines to the beginning of each input file and filling the author and title into the respective fields.

Formatting etc. should be adaptable to any specific needs. (The toc entry also can be formatted in place...)

(*I had some special complications since I needed the authors set above the chapter heading, which meant using a Koma function [setchapterpreamble] conflicting with titlesec. If this is needed, headings must be formatted "koma-style", e.g. `\setkomafont{chapter}{\rmfamily\scshape\large}`.)